# Couldn't get All categories Collection Magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I am facing an issue on the Live site that category collection only returns the specific level categories the same code is working fine on Localhost

[image]

Here is My Code

```
public function getAllCategory(int $storeId = 0){


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();


    $catagoryList=array();
    $result=array();
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $collection->setStore($storeId);

    if ($collection->count() < 1) {
        $result[0]['success']=false;
        $message = __('Category doesn\'t exist.');
        $result[0]['message']=$this->appApiHelper->translate($message);
        $result[0]['data']=null;

        return $result;
    }

    $collectionChild = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collectionChild->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('level', 4);
    $collectionChild->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $collectionChild->setStore($storeId);
    $result[0]['success']=true;
    if ($collectionChild->count() < 1) {
        foreach ($collection as $category) {

            $catagoryList=array();
            $catagoryList['entity_id'] = $category['entity_id'];
            $catagoryList['name'] = $category->getName();
            if($category->getImageUrl() != null)
            {
                $catagoryList['image_url'] = $baseUrl.$category->getImageUrl();
            }
            else
            {
                $catagoryList['image_url'] = false;
            }

            $catagoryList['url_path'] = $category->getUrlPath();
            $catagoryList['description'] = $category->getDescription();
            $catagoryList['tag_line'] = $category->getTagLine();
            $result[0]['data'][]=$catagoryList;

        }
    }else{
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $catagoryList=array();
            $catagoryList['entity_id'] = $category['entity_id'];
            $catagoryList['name'] = $category->getName();
            if($category->getImageUrl() != null)
            {
                $catagoryList['image_url'] = $baseUrl.$category->getImageUrl();
            }
            else
            {
                $catagoryList['image_url'] = false;
            }
            $catagoryList['url_path'] = $category->getUrlPath();
            $catagoryList['description'] = $category->getDescription();
            $catagoryList['tag_line'] = $category->getTagLine();
          foreach ($collectionChild as $childcategory) {
            $childCatagoryList=array();
            if ($childcategory['parent_id']==$category['entity_id']) {
                $childCatagoryList['entity_id'] = $childcategory['entity_id'];
                $childCatagoryList['name'] = $childcategory->getName();
                $childCatagoryList['image_url'] = $childcategory->getImageUrl();
                $childCatagoryList['url_path'] = $childcategory->getUrlPath();
                $childCatagoryList['description'] = $category->getDescription();
                $childCatagoryList['tag_line'] = $category->getTagLine();    
              $catagoryList['children'][] = $childCatagoryList;
            }

        }
         $result[0]['data'][]=$catagoryList;
      }
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Check if your other Environment has those category enabled properly

Comment: Yes these are enabled

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with POSTMAN IDK why it is showing the same response over and over again, I call the API in Google Chorome and then call again on Postman issue resolved !!